# Angular 4 convert json to xml

Tags: json, xml, angular

I have a need to convert json to xml in angular 4. the client has written has written a WCF that will accept an xml parameter to the method.
We, in angular, rather use json for obvious reasons.

We decided to write a json object and convert it to xml.
I already know how to do to opposite way, xml to json:

```
 xml2json(xml, tab) {
    var X = {
      toObj: function (xml) {
        var o = {};
        if (xml.nodeType == 1) {   // element node ..
          if (xml.attributes.length)   // element with attributes  ..
            for (var i = 0; i < xml.attributes.length; i++)
              o["@" + xml.attributes[i].nodeName] = (xml.attributes[i].nodeValue || "").toString();
          if (xml.firstChild) { // element has child nodes ..
            var textChild = 0, cdataChild = 0, hasElementChild = false;
            for (var n = xml.firstChild; n; n = n.nextSibling) {
              if (n.nodeType == 1) hasElementChild = true;
              else if (n.nodeType == 3 && n.nodeValue.match(/[^ \f\n\r\t\v]/)) textChild++; // non-whitespace text
              else if (n.nodeType == 4) cdataChild++; // cdata section node
            }
            if (hasElementChild) {
              if (textChild < 2 && cdataChild < 2) { // structured element with evtl. a single text or/and cdata node ..
                X.removeWhite(xml);
                for (var n = xml.firstChild; n; n = n.nextSibling) {
                  if (n.nodeType == 3)  // text node
                    o["#text"] = X.escape(n.nodeValue);
                  else if (n.nodeType == 4)  // cdata node
                    o["#cdata"] = X.escape(n.nodeValue);
                  else if (o[n.nodeName]) {  // multiple occurence of element ..
                    if (o[n.nodeName] instanceof Array)
                      o[n.nodeName][o[n.nodeName].length] = X.toObj(n);
                    else
                      o[n.nodeName] = [o[n.nodeName], X.toObj(n)];
                  }
                  else  // first occurence of element..
                    o[n.nodeName] = X.toObj(n);
                }
              }
              else { // mixed content
                if (!xml.attributes.length)
                  o = X.escape(X.innerXml(xml));
                else
                  o["#text"] = X.escape(X.innerXml(xml));
              }
            }
            else if (textChild) { // pure text
              if (!xml.attributes.length)
                o = X.escape(X.innerXml(xml));
              else
                o["#text"] = X.escape(X.innerXml(xml));
            }
            else if (cdataChild) { // cdata
              if (cdataChild > 1)
                o = X.escape(X.innerXml(xml));
              else
                for (var n = xml.firstChild; n; n = n.nextSibling)
                  o["#cdata"] = X.escape(n.nodeValue);
            }
          }
          if (!xml.attributes.length && !xml.firstChild) o = null;
        }
        else if (xml.nodeType == 9) { // document.node
          o = X.toObj(xml.documentElement);
        }
        else
          alert("unhandled node type: " + xml.nodeType);
        return o;
      },
      toJson: function (o, name, ind) {
        var json = name ? ("\"" + name + "\"") : "";
        if (o instanceof Array) {
          for (var i = 0, n = o.length; i < n; i++)
            o[i] = X.toJson(o[i], "", ind + "\t");
          json += (name ? ":[" : "[") + (o.length > 1 ? ("\n" + ind + "\t" + o.join(",\n" + ind + "\t") + "\n" + ind) : o.join("")) + "]";
        }
        else if (o == null)
          json += (name && ":") + "null";
        else if (typeof (o) == "object") {
          var arr = [];
          for (var m in o)
            arr[arr.length] = X.toJson(o[m], m, ind + "\t");
          json += (name ? ":{" : "{") + (arr.length > 1 ? ("\n" + ind + "\t" + arr.join(",\n" + ind + "\t") + "\n" + ind) : arr.join("")) + "}";
        }
        else if (typeof (o) == "string")
          json += (name && ":") + "\"" + o.toString() + "\"";
        else
          json += (name && ":") + o.toString();
        return json;
      },
      innerXml: function (node) {
        var s = ""
        if ("innerHTML" in node)
          s = node.innerHTML;
        else {
          var asXml = function (n) {
            var s = "";
            if (n.nodeType == 1) {
              s += "<" + n.nodeName;
              for (var i = 0; i < n.attributes.length; i++)
                s += " " + n.attributes[i].nodeName + "=\"" + (n.attributes[i].nodeValue || "").toString() + "\"";
              if (n.firstChild) {
                s += ">";
                for (var c = n.firstChild; c; c = c.nextSibling)
                  s += asXml(c);
                s += "</" + n.nodeName + ">";
              }
              else
                s += "/>";
            }
            else if (n.nodeType == 3)
              s += n.nodeValue;
            else if (n.nodeType == 4)
              s += "<![CDATA[" + n.nodeValue + "]]>";
            return s;
          };
          for (var c = node.firstChild; c; c = c.nextSibling)
            s += asXml(c);
        }
        return s;
      },
      escape: function (txt) {
        return txt.replace(/[\\]/g, "\\\\")
          .replace(/[\"]/g, '\\"')
          .replace(/[\n]/g, '\\n')
          .replace(/[\r]/g, '\\r');
      },
      removeWhite: function (e) {
        e.normalize();
        for (var n = e.firstChild; n;) {
          if (n.nodeType == 3) {  // text node
            if (!n.nodeValue.match(/[^ \f\n\r\t\v]/)) { // pure whitespace text node
              var nxt = n.nextSibling;
              e.removeChild(n);
              n = nxt;
            }
            else
              n = n.nextSibling;
          }
          else if (n.nodeType == 1) {  // element node
            X.removeWhite(n);
            n = n.nextSibling;
          }
          else                      // any other node
            n = n.nextSibling;
        }
        return e;
      }
    };
    if (xml.nodeType == 9) // document node
      xml = xml.documentElement;
    var json = X.toJson(X.toObj(X.removeWhite(xml)), xml.nodeName, "\t");
    return "{\n" + tab + (tab ? json.replace(/\t/g, tab) : json.replace(/\t|\n/g, "")) + "\n}";
  }
```

Now I need to know, how to convert the json object to xml string or object.

thanks in advance!

Comment: https://github.com/nashwaan/xml-js

Comment: how did I not know about this wonderful repo?

Comment: I guess you were to busy trying to reinvent the wheel instead of using google to search for an already functional one :P

Answer (score 1):

You can try this way [js2xmlparser npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/js2xmlparser)

install `npm i js2xmlparser`

```
import * as JsonToXML from "js2xmlparser";
console.log(JsonToXML.parse("person", this.obj));
```

Here `this.obj` is your JSON object

[Stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-json-2-xml-example)

Answer (score 0):

```
jsonToXML(json) {
    let xml = '';
    // tslint:disable: forin
    for (const prop in json) {
      xml += json[prop] instanceof Array ? '' : '<' + prop + '>';
      if (json[prop] instanceof Array) {
        for (const array in json[prop]) {
          xml += '<' + prop + '>';
          xml += this.jsonToXML(new Object(json[prop][array]));
          xml += '</' + prop + '>';
        }
      } else if (typeof json[prop] === 'object') {
        xml += this.jsonToXML(new Object(json[prop]));
      } else {
        xml += json[prop];
      }
      xml += json[prop] instanceof Array ? '' : '</' + prop + '>';
    }
    xml = xml.replace(/<\/?[0-9]{1,}>/g, '');
    return xml;
  }
```